# Help Hacking Gruber's Liberal URL Regex

Tags: php, regex, url, gruber

I've taken the [Liberal URL Regex from Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls), merged it with [some of Alan Storm improvements](http://alanstorm.com/url_regex_explained) and hacked my way into fixing some bugs like support for IDN chars inside parentheses. This is what I've:

```
/(?:[\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:(?:\([^\s()<>]*\)[^\s()<>]*)+|[^[:punct:]\s]|\/)/
```

However I've encountered a bug that I'm not being able to solve:

```
'www.dsd(sd)sdsd.com' // can also be the valid 'www.dsd.com/whatever(whatever)'
```

The above URL is being recognized as `www.dsd(sd)sdsd.com'` (or `www.dsd.com/whatever(whatever)'`) instead of `www.dsd(sd)sdsd.com` (or `www.dsd.com/whatever(whatever)`). This only seems to happen when the URL has parentheses, since the following URL:

```
'www.sampleurl.com'
```

Is correctly being recognized as `www.sampleurl.com`.

I think **the `[^[:punct:]\s]|\/` part of the regex is not being executed when the URL has parentheses**, I've been trying for some time but I can't seem to find a solution. Can anyone help me?

For commodity, I've set up a [**Rubular permalink** with the regex and some test data](http://www.rubular.com/regexes/12833) (the last URL fails).

---

I think that Gruber's regex was a little rushed, for instance it doesn't match URL's like:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_(Special)_For_You
```

I'm even more impressed by seeing that both [Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) and [Alan](http://alanstorm.com/url_regex_explained) missed this really simple typo:

```
\([\w\d]+\)
```

**Wouldn't `\(\w+\)` be enough? :S**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like [Gruber has revised his regular expression](http://gist.github.com/249502/):

```
\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.])(?:[^\s()<>]+|\([^\s()<>]+\))+(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)|[^`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’\s]))
```

[Works just fine now](http://www.rubular.com/regexes/12927).

Comment: Tried in Php 8.1.22 with preg_match() i have a Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('

Answer (score 1):

www.dsd(sd)sdsd.com is not a valid domain name.

If you had `'www.dsd.com/whatever(whatever)'`, it would be recognized correctly. (Or at least is in my tests)

Comment: Hm, true. I tested using the original Daring Fireball expression (that I use myself). I'm not a regex expert, so pending any other solution, I would remove Alan Storm's improvements (because I believe they are useless/unnecessary)

Comment: The Daring Fireball expression only matches 0-9a-Z inside parentheses.

Comment: www.url.com/something(xyz) ... the parens part is how cookieless sessions correlate the key in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /(?:[\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:(?:\([^\s()<>]*\)[^\s()<>]*)+|[^[:punct:]\s]|\/)/
  www.                   |               |            |
                          dsd            |            |
                                          (sd)        |
                                                       sdsd.com'
```

That's how I think this breaks down... the bit of the regex above `(sd)` starts with an escaped open paren, then a stared char class matching `sd`, then an escaped closing paren, and the next thing is `[^\s()<>]*` which matches `sdsd.com'`.